# Dates Mysteriously Converted to Numeric Data Once Put Into Data Frame

Tags: r

I am using an API to get some data. To get the data, I use:

```
library(httr)
data=GET(url, add_headers(Authorization=token))
mydata=content(data)$data
```

In a gross oversimplification, I then format all the data like so:

```
day=unlist(lapply(mydata,'[[', 1))
price=as.numeric(lapply(mydata, '[[',2))
fulldf=as.data.frame(cbind(day,price))
```

With `str(fulldf)` I see that each column is factor data despite using `as.numeric`. Documentation for `?factor` says "To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended..." So I use that as follows:

```
day=as.Date(levels(fulldf$day))[fulldf$day]
price=as.numeric(levels(fulldf$price))[fulldf$price]
fulldf=as.data.frame(cbind(day,price))
```

What is strange to me is that `str(day)` shows a date vector as expected (format is "yyyy-mm-dd"), but `str(fulldf$day)` shows a numeric vector. What am I doing wrong here? Is it something in an earlier step with wrapping `lapply` in `as.Date` or is it the `as.data.frame` that is causing problems?

Comment: A reproducible example would make it much easier to help you. Post `dput(mydata)` Or `dput(fulldf)` .

Comment: I can't share the actual data unfortunately. Any thoughts appreciated though, I'm stumped

Comment: In addition to @SmokeyShakers's answer, `matrix` columns can only be of the same type. So what you want is a `data.frame, which may contain different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`price` and `date` are vectors when you call `cbind`,  so they become a matrix first.  Matrices can't be of type `Date`. They must be a primitive data type.

You could call the dataframe cbind method directly:

```
cbind.data.frame(day,price)
```

Or simpler, per @jay.sf:

```
data.frame(day, price)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
fulldf <- data.frame(day = sapply(mydata,'[[', 1), price = sapply(mydata, '[[',2))
fulldf$day <- as.Date(fulldf$day)
```